# Smart grouping in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to make  sort of cluster, tried to use row_number, rank and dense_rank but nothing worked.

```
USER  START_DATE        ID_TO_CLUSTER  END_DATE          NEW FIELD_SESSION
262   01/10/2017 00:01  4              01/10/2017 00:03  S1
262   01/10/2017 00:02  4              01/10/2017 00:03  S1
262   01/10/2017 00:03  0              01/10/2017 00:03  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 00:03  1              01/10/2017 00:03  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 00:03  7              01/10/2017 00:03  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 00:03  2              01/10/2017 00:07  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 00:07  3              01/10/2017 00:07  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 00:07  4              01/10/2017 00:11  S2
262   01/10/2017 00:07  4              01/10/2017 00:11  S2
262   01/10/2017 00:11  7              01/10/2017 00:11  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 00:11  9              01/10/2017 00:11  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 16:28  0              01/10/2017 16:30  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 16:28  1              01/10/2017 16:28  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 16:30  2              01/10/2017 16:30  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 16:30  3              01/10/2017 16:30  NO SESSION 
262   01/10/2017 16:30  4              01/10/2017 16:36  S3
262   01/10/2017 16:30  4              01/10/2017 16:36  S3
262   01/10/2017 16:36  4              01/10/2017 16:36  S3
```

Basically I need to group ID_TO_CLUSTER in a Session (new_field_session) when id_to_cluster is duplicated in a subsequent time, in order to get the min start_date and the max end date for each cluster.

Can you help me?

**Update:**

In response to Leran 2002's Answer: the proposed solution works only when rows to group are 2 and doesn't when they are three or more. Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the sample data provided? I suspect you should take a look at the [`gaps-and-islands`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands?mixed=1) tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  GroupNum,
  ID_TO_CLUSTER,
  NEW_FIELD_SESSION,
  MIN(START_DATE) MIN_START_DATE,
  MAX(END_DATE) MAX_END_DATE
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      CASE WHEN NEW_FIELD_SESSION=PrevSession THEN LAG(RowNum)OVER(ORDER BY RowNum) ELSE RowNum END GroupNum
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          *,
          LAG(NEW_FIELD_SESSION)OVER(ORDER BY START_DATE,ID_TO_CLUSTER) PrevSession,
          LEAD(NEW_FIELD_SESSION)OVER(ORDER BY START_DATE,ID_TO_CLUSTER) NextSession,
          ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY START_DATE,ID_TO_CLUSTER) RowNum
        FROM [Your table]
      ) q
    WHERE (PrevSession IS NULL OR NextSession IS NULL OR NEW_FIELD_SESSION<>PrevSession OR NEW_FIELD_SESSION<>NextSession)
  ) q
GROUP BY GroupNum,ID_TO_CLUSTER,NEW_FIELD_SESSION
```

I tested it on SQLServer 2014.

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e983/1

Comment: I hope that it what you need and it works rightly. ))